# I'm not sure about if GraalVM native image has all the advantages in any system environment

Tags: java, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I did some experiments according to the following code, and obtained some experimental results. Mainly compare three cases: 1. without JIT, 2. JIT (default), 3. Execution file generated after Graal native-image

1. The fastest execution result in my 8G memory environment turned out to be "Without JIT". (I close the JIT myself and execute)
2. The execution time of Graal native-image and JIT are longer than that of 2G in the environment of 8G memory.
3. "Without JIT" and JIT are executed in 8G and 2G of memory, 8G takes up less memory when executing programs. (2G is 462MB vs. 8G is 457MB)

I would like to know if anyone has done relevant tests and got the experimental results that match me, or that my experimental process is wrong.

This is my code.

```
public class testmemory{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int nums2 = 1024*1024*16;
        int[][] arr2 = new int[nums2][2];
        for(int i = 0;i < arr2.length;i++){
            arr2[i][0] = i;
            arr2[i][1] = i;
        }

        long memory2 = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1024/1024 - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024 / 1024;
        //long memory2 = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1024/1024;
        System.out.println("memory used："+memory2+"MB");
    }
}
```

This is my experimental data. I'm sorry, I didn't sort it out in the first place.

[This is the experimental data under the memory configuration of 2G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPF7.png)

[This is the experimental data under the memory configuration of 8G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly3Ng.png)

Comment: "fastest execution", "execution time" maybe you could clarify what we are talking about? is it seconds/microseconds? and what are you testing, the memory array occupies?

Comment: The time unit of the test is seconds. 
Mainly want to test the execution time and memory usage at different memory sizes. Thanks for your inquiry and addition !

Comment: but would you like to share the results? it's hard to judge based on nothing

Comment: Your code is not doing anything useful; in the best case, a static compiler will eliminate everything but the last print statement. And, of course, such a simple program does not benefit from a JIT. Which aspect of the execution environment should affect this program?

Comment: Of course, I'm also concerned about whether it's hard to convey what I mean without experimental data.

Comment: Reply to Holger: I understand what you mean, but I have obtained the exact memory usage value in the test.(more than ten times)

Comment: I have posted my experimental data. The memory usage below is the average value, and the difference between the measured values ​​will not exceed 1MB. 
Thank you very much for the above two answers !

Comment: > "Without JIT". (I close the JIT myself and execute)

What does that mean? `-XX:-UseJVMCICompiler`? `-Xint`? How can you "close the JIT"?

Comment: Should be corrected to temporarily disable, not close . Sorry for the wrong words in the translation. I use in  `java -Djava.compiler=NONE <class>`

Answer (score 2):

In general, GraalVM native images are going to

- Have much faster startup (compared to running under a JVM)
- Be slightly more compact (compared to JRE + application jars)
- Have reduced peak performance (as they are compiled once and ahead of time, while JVM can recompile/reoptimize code as it is being run)

Comment: I know this knowledge before the operation, I want to know if someone has done the experiment.